# Linkerd multicluster: probe-gateway mirrored from cluster X has no endpoints

Tags: kubernetes

I have many clusters running prometheus and I want to use prometheus federation to be able to do aggregations with the metrics in one central grafana dashboard. In order to achieve it, I have added an extra cluster with just a prometheus that will scrape the prometheus instances on the other clusters, but I need to make possible inter-cluster connectivity before.

I read that linkerd has a multicluster plugin that provides this kind of multicluster connectivity. I followed the steps on the official tutorial but I'm getting the next error:

> Switched to context "np-main".
> victor@xxx:~/projects/np$ linkerd multicluster check
> linkerd-multicluster
> ✔ Link CRD exists
> ✔ Link resources are valid
> np-foo
> ✔ remote cluster access credentials are valid
> np-foo
> ✔ clusters share trust anchors
> np-foo
> ✔ service mirror controller has required permissions
> np-foo
> ✔ service mirror controllers are running
> np-foo
> ❌ probe services able to communicate with all gateway mirrors
>
> - probe-gateway-np-foo.linkerd-multicluster mirrored from cluster [np-foo] has no endpoints
> - see https://linkerd.io/2/checks/#l5d-multicluster-gateways-endpoints for hints

> ✔ multicluster extension proxies are healthy
> ‼ multicluster extension proxies are up-to-date
>
> - some proxies are not running the current version:
> - linkerd-gateway-7d484d9fdf-95rpr (edge-24.2.5)
> - linkerd-service-mirror-np-foo-6c9fff5b56-wvvlq (edge-24.2.5)
> - see https://linkerd.io/2/checks/#l5d-multicluster-proxy-cp-version for hints

> ✔ multicluster extension proxies and cli versions match
> Status check results are ❌

I have tried exporting not only the prometheus-operated service (the one to scrape from the central prometheus) but also a dummy golang API and none of them are being mirrored at the central cluster.

I have ran through the steps many times and all the resources are installed and running. I don't know what I'm missing.

I'm considering trying Istio/Consul service meshes instead. Other workarounds/alternatives would be considerated.